# Python - not working serial commands

Tags: python, macos, window, byte, pyserial

Trying to send commands to the hardware: Laser on and off. But Python is failing and the hardware never getting the command.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Command list:

[image]

ss.py:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial', serial.EIGHTBITS, serial.PARITY_NONE, serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
print(ser.name)
# if i add ' then also error
ser.write(\xA0h\xC1h\x01\x00h\xSt.\xAFh)

ser.close()
```

On execute error occure:

```
  File "ss.py", line 5
    ser.write(\xA0h\xC1h\x01\x00h\xSt.\xAFh)
                                           ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

or

Error:

```
$ python ss.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ss.py", line 3, in <module>
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial', serial.EIGHTBITS, serial.PARITY_NONE, serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 220, in __init__
    self.bytesize = bytesize
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 306, in bytesize
    raise ValueError("Not a valid byte size: {!r}".format(bytesize))
ValueError: Not a valid byte size: 'N'
```

Comment: When i use `b'\xA0h\xC1h\x01\x00h\x00h\xAFh'` then its also giving ERROR as my last EDIT. "ValueError: Not a valid byte size: 'N'
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you need to send the commands one at a time, rather than as a single string.

```
for command in [b'0xA0h', b'0xC1h', b'0x01', b'0x00h', b'0xSt', b'0xAFh']:
    ser.write(command)
```

Notice that I have also altered the beginning of each subcommand to indicate that it is a hex value.

========EDIT========

Looking at the command list in your question, I wonder if you have used the "Switch on" command to make sure the system is on?

I also see that it is possible to send a string to query the device.  Have you tried that?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/26018521/  - i applied this code but the hardware do not turn on the LASER light. How can you read all the output from the hardware after sending ?

Comment: That that code-paste, you don't create the Serial object with the necessary flags.  Have you tried `ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial', serial.EIGHTBITS, serial.PARITY_NONE, serial.STOPBITS_ONE)` as you wrote in your original question?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/26018563/ - also this failing. Can you see how to read everything from the hardware after the command we sent?

Comment: I have edited my answer with some additional information.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2ZLd.png - Please see my EDIT with this screen shot. Command packet format has to be as mentioned , which is 6 byte not string.

Comment: System is switched on, i can see a TV display and lights. Also from OSX when i send serial command its sent out but the command packet format is maybe still invalid. how we are sending, therefore we need to read everything from the hardware response.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYXS6.png - We need to read the return result from the hardware to make sure our command packet format is correctly sent or not?

Comment: If you have an example of sending serial data from OSX that actually works, can you provide that as well?  How did you do that?